# Reputation Tab sometimes has recent score, sometimes not

Tags: discussion, reputation, recent-activity, reputation-page

On my laptop that I use from home, my reputation link looks like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/210754?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2009-12-01&EndDate=2009-12-03

But on my desktop at work, the start/end dates aren't there and I can't track my meteroic rise to fame minute by minute.  Don't know why I care except that it's different.  Can anyone shed light?

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1459 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28393

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the envelope, you get the link with no start/end date parameters. That is (in theory) activity since your last login. So when you get home you're looking at activity since you left the office.

Once you click on one of the tabs or one of the today/yesterday/etc buttons, the StartDate/EndDate params will be added to the URL.  You must have clicked on "this month" on your work machine without realizing it.

http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/5166/datelinks.png

Comment: That doesn't quite explain why the default is different across different computers, does it?

Comment: @Romain Muller: you're right, I clarified my answer.